# How to manage/alerts message in Chromedriver with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium to get Magnet links from a website, but when I click on the Chrome Webdriver link it asks me if I want to open the magnet link in uTorrent (Open utorrent?), and that alert has two buttons, `Open uTorrent` and `Cancel` as you can see in the picture. [image]

I want to know how to manage,

1- if can I Send Keys, to chrome to press `LEFT_ARROW` and `ENTER` and Send the link to uTorrent

2- Get/take the alert with selenium in some way and press "Open uTorrent" `Alert = Driver.Alerts().ClickOK()`

3- Change the settings for Chrome webdriver to disable this alert and send all the links with no alerts.

4- Or any other idea...

All this in Python. Using Chrome Webdriver on Windows 10.

```
######### here is my attempt to manage the alert/notification
alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)
print("Left")
alert.send_keys(keys.ENTER)
print("ENTER")

print('Send it to uTorrent')
t.sleep(10)
# Close the tab with URL B
driver.close()
#########
```

Here is the full code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time as t
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

sobrecarga = "El servidor se encuentra sobrecargado en estos momentos"
acceder = "acceder"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.epublibre.org") 

ps = driver.page_source
t.sleep(2)
if sobrecarga in ps:
    print("Overcharge = " + str(sobrecarga in ps))
    #the page is overcharge
    UserName = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/input')
    UserName.send_keys('USER')
    PwdUser = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input')
    PwdUser.send_keys('PASSWORD')
    Entrar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/input[2]')
    Entrar.click()
    t.sleep(2)
elif acceder in ps:
    print("Acceder = " + str(acceder in ps))
    t.sleep(2)
    #Click "Acceder" link
    GetAccess = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div/a[2]')                  
    GetAccess.click()
    t.sleep(2)
    UserName = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txt_user"]')
    UserName.send_keys("USER")
    PwdUser = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txt_pass"]')
    PwdUser.send_keys("PASSWORD")
    Entrar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[6]/div/input')
    Entrar.click()

t.sleep(2)
#go to home page
HomePage = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a')
HomePage.click()
#goto novedades
novedades = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[6]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[1]/div/span/a')
novedades.click()
t.sleep(2)

#Every page (inside the webpage) has several links, that I want to click
for i in range(1,5): #I want to see just the first 5 pages 
    for j in range(0,18): #Go for every link inside the page inthe webpage
        myBook = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[7]/div/div[2]/div[' + str(j+1) + ']/div/a') #take the link, are 18 in total

        libro = myBook.get_attribute('href') #get the href (the link itself)
        print('Este es el link: ' + libro) # just a notification for me
        # Open a new tab
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        # Switch to the new tab and 
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        #open URL "libro"
        driver.get(libro)

        #CLICK TO SEND TO UTORRENT (ATTEMPT)
        t.sleep(2)
        #there is a magnet link in the new webpage
        MagnetLink = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="en_desc"]')
        #and when click the magnet link chrome ask me "Open uTorrent"
        MagnetLink.click()
        t.sleep(10)


        ######### here is my attempt to manage the alert/notification
        alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)
        print("Left")
        alert.send_keys(keys.ENTER)
        print("ENTER")

        print('Send it to uTorrent')
        t.sleep(10)
        # Close the tab with URL B
        driver.close()
        ######### 


        # Switch back to the first tab with URL A
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
        print("Current Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)

    siguiente = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[8]/div/div/ul/li[6]/a') #/html/body/div/div[8]/div/div/ul/li[6]/a #//*[@id="pagina"]/a
    siguiente.click()
```

Comment: Setting unexpected alert behavior might help... Note: "notify" just means throws exception and this happens right before the next webdriver action occurs: 
 https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.html  (you set this in ChromeDriver options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but you can save the magnet link in a string, then use [os.startfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.startfile) to open it in your torrernt client:

`os.startfile(magnet_link)`

Answer (score 0):

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```